# How does he get on at school?

Tags: present-tense

Can present simple be used in this sentence below? ( "How does Peter get on at school?")

"How is Peter getting on at school? Very well. He seems to like the life."

Comment: Why would you think that it can't be used that way?

Comment: As usual, the present continuous refers to something happening now, and the present simple refers to things in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammatically that's fine.

In actual use, we are talking about Peter's progress... so present continuous would be the natural tense to use.